# error: Invalid Signature when uploading files on dropbox

Tags: post, dropbox, libcurl, signature

I am trying to develop a desktop application that uses dropbox. I am using C++, libcurl (for the requests) liboauthcpp (for the authentication) and the Rest API (from dropbox).

Since I have successed the authentication and some more operations (list and download file), I cannot manage to upload a file. I am receiving the following error: {"error": "Invalid signature."}

Here is my code:

```
m_upload_url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/sandbox/";

        OAuth::Consumer consumer(m_consumer_key, m_consumer_secret);
        OAuth::KeyValuePairs access_token_resp_data = OAuth::ParseKeyValuePairs(m_access_token_Response);
        OAuth::Token access_token = OAuth::Token::extract( access_token_resp_data );
        OAuth::Client  oauth = OAuth::Client(&consumer, &access_token);
        string oAuthQueryString = oauth.getURLQueryString( OAuth::Http::Post, m_upload_url);

        string upload_Request = (string(m_upload_url) + string("?") + oAuthQueryString);

       CURL *curl;
         CURLcode res;

         struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
         struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
         struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
         static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

         curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

         /* Fill in the file upload field */
         curl_formadd(&formpost,
                      &lastptr,
                      CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
                      CURLFORM_FILE, "C:/Users/Desktop/textfile.txt",
                      CURLFORM_END);

         /* Fill in the filename field */
         curl_formadd(&formpost,
                      &lastptr,
                      CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name",
                      CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "textfile",
                      CURLFORM_END);


         /* Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */
         curl_formadd(&formpost,
                      &lastptr,
                      CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
                      CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
                      CURLFORM_END);

         curl = curl_easy_init();
         /* initalize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is not
            wanted */
         headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
         if(curl) {
           /* what URL that receives this POST */
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, upload_Request.c_str());
             /* only disable 100-continue header if explicitly requested */
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, 1L);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeFunction);
           curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

           /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
           res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
           string response = string(gData);

           qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(response);

           /* Check for errors */
           if(res != CURLE_OK)
           qDebug() << "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n" << curl_easy_strerror(res);

           /* always cleanup */
           curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

           /* then cleanup the formpost chain */
           curl_formfree(formpost);
           /* free slist */
           curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);
         }
```

and here is the writeFunction:

```
char gData[1024*1024];
unsigned int gDataLen = 0;

size_t writeFunction( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
{
    memcpy( &( gData[gDataLen] ), ptr, (size * nmemb) );
    gDataLen += (size * nmemb);
    gData[ gDataLen ] = '\0';
    return (size * nmemb);
}
```

Any ideas, please?

EDIT:

Here is the request that the present code produces:
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/sandbox/?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_nonce=13xxxxxx83cf&oauth_signature=xxxxxx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxx%xx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1371107283&oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_version=1.0

and the request that I produse with the plaintext method:
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/sandbox/?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Response that O get in both cases:
{"error": "Invalid signature."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OAuth signature method are you using? If it's anything but plaintext, then I believe the problem is that you're not passing the body of the HTTP request to `getURLQueryString`. The body needs to be part of the string that's signed. This explains why you've been able to get a few `GET` operations to work; those requests don't have a body.

Side note: it looks like you're using the POST form of file upload, which, [as the docs say](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-POST) is considerably more complex than [PUT](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put). I think your life will be better if you switch. :-) For example, I think the `submit` field that you're adding will probably cause the call to not work.

**EDIT**: Here's a full working example using a manually-constructed plaintext signature. Fill in the app key, app secret, token, and token secret, and be sure to have a file called "hello.txt" for this to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

size_t read_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    return fread(ptr,size,nmeb,(FILE*)stream);
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  FILE * rfp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");

  string appkey = "<APP KEY>";
  string appsecret = "<APP SECRET>";
  string token = "<ACCESS TOKEN>";
  string token_secret = "<ACCESS TOKEN SECRET>";

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/hello.txt");

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    string header = "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"" + appkey + "\", oauth_token=\"" + token + "\", oauth_signature=\"" + appsecret + "&" + token_secret + "\"";
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, header.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, rfp);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  fclose(rfp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that I do pass the body of the HTTP request to getURLQueryString, by writing:

Comment: The PUT method requires a different endpoint. It should be `https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/<root>/<path>`. It also expects the body of the HTTP request to simply be the file contents, not a form-encoded POST. If you try these changes, please update your question with the new code. (**Edited** since I was incorrect about the signature looking right.)

Comment: Oh, actually, your plaintext signature doesn't look correct (at least not what Dropbox expects). See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/20 for details.

Comment: Thanks a million!! I couldn't realize the header that is provided by dropbox was actually ready. When I was trying to use the PLAINTEXT method I was trying to make it on my own...

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone used liboauthcpp? I suspect that my mistake is in the way I use getURLQueryString.. I am passing the url into this function, but I am not sure if I have to pass the data too.
And unfortunately, there is no documentation for this library.

Comment: This is what my answer pointed out. Your code doesn't pass the body of the HTTP request to `getURLQueryString`.