# Retrieving file from Dropbox using PHP returns 403 Invalid Signature

Tags: php, dropbox

I'm trying to download all files from a specific directory in my Dropbox to a directory on my web server, if a file of the same name doesn't already.

I'm using this [SitePoint Tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/access-dropbox-using-php/) as the guide.

The problem I'm having is that the Dropbox API returns an `Invalid Signature` error when it gets to certain files. I can't see anything odd or special about these files. Some are PDFs, some are PNGs.

I've read this [could relate to OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070042/426935), but I can't figure it out.

I believe errors at the `getFile()` within the `foreach()`, depending on the file:

```
<?php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

if (!isset($access_token)) {
    header("Location: authorize.php");
    exit;
}

try {
    $session = new DropboxSession($config["dropbox"]["app_key"], $config["dropbox"]["app_secret"], $config["dropbox"]["access_type"], $access_token);

    $client = new DropboxClient($session);
    $path = "/Stuff/folder_to_download";
    $home = $client->metadata($path);

    foreach($home['contents'] as $item) {
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($item, true) . "</pre>";
        $path = $item['path'];

        if ( $item['is_dir'] == '1' )
            continue;

        // where to save it
        $dest = $config["app"]["datadir"] . "/" . basename($path);

        if ( file_exists($dest) ) {
            echo "<p>File <code>". $dest . "</code> already exists. Skipped.</p>";
            continue;
        }

        // Download file
        if ($file = $client->getFile($path, $dest)) {
            if (!empty($dest)) {
                unset($file["data"]);
                echo "<p>File saved to: <code>" . $dest . "</code></p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<strong>ERROR (" . $e->getCode() . ")</strong>: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

The `authorize.php` file [looks like this](https://github.com/phpmasterdotcom/AccessDropboxUsingPHP/blob/master/authorize.php). `bootstrap.php` [looks like this](https://github.com/phpmasterdotcom/AccessDropboxUsingPHP/blob/master/bootstrap.php).

**Update 1:** I've still not been able to resolve this error. Is there a different set of Dropbox/ PHP code I could use instead of this sitepoint one?

Here's the raw error when I remove the try/catch:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid signature.' in /myapp/lib/dropbox/rest.php:162
Stack trace:
#0 /myapp/lib/dropbox/rest.php(85): DropboxRESTClient->request('https://api-con...', 'GET', NULL, NULL, NULL, true)
#1 /myapp/lib/dropbox/session.php(278): DropboxRESTClient->get('https://api-con...', NULL, true)
#2 /myapp/lib/dropbox/client.php(106): DropboxSession->fetch('GET', 'https://api-con...', '/files/dropbox/...', Array, true)
#3 /myapp/download.php(54): DropboxClient->getFile('/Stuff/Droppod/...', '/myapp/...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /myapp/lib/dropbox/rest.php on line 162
```

The [lib/dropbox/rest.php file is on GitHub](https://github.com/phpmasterdotcom/AccessDropboxUsingPHP/blob/master/lib/dropbox/rest.php) for reference.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions of things I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this same issue, has to do with some folders/files that have special characters in the path like '&' or '$' and '(' or ')'.  Recommend that you encode the path BEFORE you make GET queries to the api otherwise you'll end up with a url like this

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/Photos & Stuff ~ Jan 2013
```

instead of properly encoded like this

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/Photos%20%26%20Stuff%20~%20Jan%202013
```

edit: Here is the code (javascript) that I used for encoding the path (works like a charm)

```
encodeURIComponent(p)
   .replace(/%2F/g, '/')
   .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
   .replace(/\(/g, '%28');
```

Comment: If you do have an encoding bug, the "invalid signature" is presumably because the URL you're signing via OAuth doesn't match the URL you're actually sending, and thus the signatures don't match. There's no way for Dropbox to know *why* the signature doesn't match.

Comment: ah that makes sense .. thanks for the clarification on that error message!

Answer (score 0):

"I've still not been able to resolve this error. Is there a different set of Dropbox/ PHP code I could use instead of this sitepoint one?"

As to that question, you could try using the official Dropbox PHP SDK: http://dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php